# JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, struts2, oracle11g

I am getting below error while fetching records and its sporadic , it gets fixed either by restarting the server or by itself after some time. I am using Struts 2, Oracle 11g, Hibernate 3.

## Error

```
2014-05-06 13:38:51 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2014-05-06 13:38:51 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - IO Error: Connection timed out
2014-05-06 13:38:51 ERROR Dispatcher:38 - Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tai.dao.UsersTaiImplDAO.listUser(UsersTaiImplDAO.java:37)
    at com.tai.web.UsersTaiAction.userLogin(UsersTaiAction.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at
```

## C3P0 Properties

```
<property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">4</property>
<property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds -->
<property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property    >
<property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property>
<property name="c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
<property name="c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">65</property>
<property name="c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>
<property name="c3p0.numHelperThreads">8</property>
<property name="c3p0.maxAdministrativeTaskTime">1</property>
```

## Code

```
public List<UsersTai> listUser(String userName, String password) {
    _logger.debug("listUser");
    List<UsersTai> usersTai = null;
    String name= userName.substring(userName.indexOf('@')).trim();
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
         session.beginTransaction();
        usersTai = session.createQuery("from UsersTai where username='" + userName +"' or username= '"+name + "' and USERPASSWORD='"+ password +"'").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. For starters, can you please tell us what version of Hibernate you are using, post the method that the exception is being thrown in and provide the entire stacktrace. We can't debug vague problems without more information.

Comment: Delete the comment and edit your question to add the stacktrace and the method that the exception is being thrown in

Comment: So which is the line 37 in your dao?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a current hibernate session if it's not available. Change the code to open a new session.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

At the end when you no longer needed it use the session factory to close a session.